# How to fix failed to fetch

Tags: updates

When i am usin sudo apt-get udate on my server i am suddenly getting a failed to fetch and I am not sure what i should change to fix this error? I am running a ubuntu 14.04 LTS Server

```
daniel@rproxy:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease                      
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                    
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources                   
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources             
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources               
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources             
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages            
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages      
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages        
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages             
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages       
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages         
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages       
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en            
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en        
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources                 
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources           
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources             
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources           
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages          
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages    
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages      
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages    
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages           
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages     
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages       
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages     
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en          
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en    
Ign http://apt.puppetlabs.com trusty InRelease                                 
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en    
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en      
Ign http://download.draios.com stable-amd64/ InRelease                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                           
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources                     
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                       
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources                     
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages              
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages                
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages              
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                     
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                 
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages               
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                    
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en              
Hit http://apt.puppetlabs.com trusty Release.gpg                               
Hit http://download.draios.com stable-amd64/ Release.gpg                       
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en              
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                
Ign http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                 
Ign http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US           
Ign http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US           
Hit http://apt.puppetlabs.com trusty Release                                   
Ign http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US             
Hit http://download.draios.com stable-amd64/ Release                           
Hit http://apt.puppetlabs.com trusty/main Sources                              
Hit http://download.draios.com stable-amd64/ Packages                          
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Hit http://apt.puppetlabs.com trusty/dependencies Sources                      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://apt.puppetlabs.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://apt.puppetlabs.com trusty/dependencies amd64 Packages               
Hit http://apt.puppetlabs.com trusty/main i386 Packages            
Hit http://apt.puppetlabs.com trusty/dependencies i386 Packages    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                       
Ign http://download.draios.com stable-amd64/ Translation-en_US                 
Ign http://download.draios.com stable-amd64/ Translation-en                    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources                    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign http://apt.puppetlabs.com trusty/dependencies Translation-en_US
Ign http://apt.puppetlabs.com trusty/dependencies Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
Ign http://apt.puppetlabs.com trusty/main Translation-en_US       
Ign http://apt.puppetlabs.com trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en         
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/release/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/release/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 1):

It cannot work because there is (no longer) a `release` PPA. Delete the list file:

```
grep -rl 'ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/release' /etc/apt | xargs sudo rm
sudo apt-get update
```

Add the stable release PPA with

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:nginx/stable
sudo apt-get update
```

or another [Ngnix PPA](https://launchpad.net/~nginx).

Comment: But can it be true that Ubuntu 14.04 isn't supported? i only see 13.10 and 14.10

Comment: Trusty is still supported, but the PPA was probably renamed.